# Question disappears after dismissing flag window

Tags: bug

I wanted to flag [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43168017/uicollectionview-flow-layout-spacing-issue), but I accidentally clicked out from the flag window.

To my amuse, the question disappeared visually altogether.

[image: The question which disappeared]

I am using Safari 12603.1.30.0.34 on macOS 10.12.4.